# ConstantStruct or ConstantArray read memory content

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm writing some llvm (3.7) pass, and I'd need some information about Constant classes. 
In the llvm-IR I'm parsing, there are "ConstantStruct", or "ConstantArray" instances which are used as initializers for global variables. For example:

```
%struct.S = type { i32, i32, i32, i32 }

@s = global [2 x %struct.S] [%struct.S { i32 6, i32 8, i32 -8, i32 -5 }, %struct.S { i32 0, i32 2, i32 -1, i32 2 }], align 4
```

My work would be much easier if I could read the memory of thoses constants, without having to recursively go through all elements (which can also be ConstantStructs or arrays).

For example, I'd need a function as

```
llvm::ConstantStruct* initializer = globalVar->getInitializer();
void* memoryContent;
int sizeInBytes = initializer->getMemoryContent(&memoryContent);
```

So far, I have to read elements one by one, which is a painful (and bug prone) process.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Any comment for the downvote would be appreciated... I don't consider that as a trivial question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just understood it's not possible due to possible ConstExpr in the initializer operands.

However, I managed to get a nice recursive implementations with a big switch on valueId.